# Packaging native image using graalvm and quarkus gave an error

Tags: quarkus

Dears,
I am following the [native image build tutorial](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image-guide.html) by quarkus to create native graalvm but i am getting the below error :

```
Error: No main manifest attribute, in /home/docker/workspace/quarkus/quarkus-getting-started/target/quarkus-getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.056 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-14T11:26:12+04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:0.11.0:native-image (default) on project quarkus-getting-started: Failed to generate a native image: Failed to build native image: Image generation failed -> [Help 1]
```

my environment :
OS : CentOS 7
Quarkus : 0.11.0
Java : Open JDK 1.8.0_181
GraalVM : 1.0.0-rc13

Using quarkus there is no main method in your app, but how to make it working using graal native image ?

Comment: Can you try doing `mvn clean` first? There is a known issue with the Manifests that you might be hitting

Comment: Thanks @geoand, it worked fine after adding clean.

Comment: Good to hear @iabughosh

Comment: Dear @geoand, I have added hibernate and JPA feature to my quarkus project and now i cannot generate native image again error is **Error: Image building with exit status 137**, can you advise about this ?. Also i have forked quarkus code into my repository and followed the guidelines for contributing, can you guide me how can i debug this locally at my machine ?.

Comment: Could you upload a reproducer project I could check out?

Comment: Yes @geoand, URL : https://github.com/iabughosh/quarkus-practice. Currently it also contains Kafka & SmallRye message, you can comment Kafka-Messages parts and try, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look most likely tomorrow

Comment: I tried your sample and it worked just fine. I should add that I was using Graal rc13

Comment: I am using same Graal too. Anyway, thanks for confirming that it is fine, i will try to confirm in other environment or debug it locally on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

The code 137 meant for me that I didn't have enough memory available for my docker image.

Try increasing the memory in your docker preferences. I set it to 10G to be sure because sometimes my build  broke or took forever.

Why don't you use the latest Quarkus version 1.4.2.Final which come with it's own Docker image.

You can use the following properties to further config your memory consumption and your GraalVM image.

```
 <quarkus.native.builder-image>quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:20.0.0-java11</quarkus.native.builder-image>-->
 <quarkus.native.native-image-xmx>8192m</quarkus.native.native-image-xmx>
```

The first one could help you use another GraalVM image that the default one.
The second one could help you improve your build time. Pay attention it has to be less than the memory you set in your docker daemon.